# Sorting 2D array with specific constraints

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've got 2D array `2d_array[x][y]` and for specific x I need to choose a y with the highest value, with specific constraints. Also array is fixed and x range is 0-24 and y range is 0-3. X is defined by a position vector as seen below.

These constraints are :

-if `x == 0` then `y != 0`

-if `x == 4` then `y != 2`

-if `x == 0-4` then `y != 3`

-if `x == 20-24` then `y != 4`

I tried something like that(note this.x is just an arbitrary value between 0-24):

```
    std::vector<float,float> position = { 4, 0};
    int x = pos.x + (5 * pos.y); //4 for test, change it for edge cases
    int bestY= 0;
    float highestReward = 2d_array[x][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (2d_array[x][i] > highestReward) {
            if (((bestY == 0 && x == 0) || (bestY == 1 && x == 4)) || ((bestY == 2 && (x >= 0 && x <= 4)) || (bestY == 3 && (x >= 0 && x <= 24))) {
                bestY++;
            }
            else {
                highestReward = 2d_array[x][i];
                bestY = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I update position accordingly:

```
 if (bestY == 0) pos.x--;
 if (bestY == 1) pos.x++;
 if (bestY == 2) pos.y--;
 if (bestY == 3) pos.y++;
```

But it just keeps overflowing position, so when I try to read in the next iteration I just have access violation.

Comment: Did you mean constraints in place of boundaries?

Comment: `x == 0-4`: If you want to check whether x is in range [0, 4] then, please, write: `(x >= 0 && x <= 4)`. `x == 0-4` is the same as `x == -4`. In C++ (and every other language I can remember), `-` has always the meaning of unary or binary minus (i.e. negation or subtraction). I've never seen it for ranges. (Though, I have: in reg. expressions for character classes. ;-) But, that's something completely different.)

Comment: Yes I meant constraints. Yeah I do that in code, don't really know why I didn't put it in. Both should be corrected in a minute.

Comment: Please, make a [MCVE] for your issue.

Comment: Fixed so it's more clear.

Comment: A [MCVE] is something which I can copy/paste into an online compiler to reproduce your issue... ;-)

Comment: This is very unclear. A minimal reproducable example would make it easy. At the very least the content of the `2d_array` are needed as are the expected values of `bestY` and `highestReward`.

Comment: I added extra code so it now should make more sense. 2d_array is just a float array with numbers assigned randomly (for now). bestY is  y value in 2d_array that has the highest value, so I have to choose bestY which has the highest value out of 4 possible y values.

Comment: Sorry, again: A [mcve] is something which I can **copy/paste into an online compiler, compile, and run** to reproduce your issue... (I'm sure that [`std::vector<float, float>` will prevent compiling definitely](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b730ba79dca3d3ea), not to mention the missing `main()` function and the sample data to run.)